# How to configure sql developer with oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, oracle-sql-developer

I'm trying to connect sql developer to a fresh installation of oracle:

I can connect to sys user via sqlplus
I can connect to sys user via sql developer when I select Connection Type "Local\Bequeath".
But I guess it didn't been connected to the PDB, just to the container.

I've created user called demo with following command:

```
alter session set container=pdborcl;
create user demo identified by password QUOTA unlimited on users account unlock;
```

I'm trying to connect to the DB with username and password like I did in oracle 11g. 
To user: `sys as sysdba`, And to the new created user `demo`.

I don't care about pdb, but as I understood there is no other option in oracle 12c...

I've tried to set entry called PDBORCL in the tnsnames.ora, 
I've also have tried to use service name PDBORCL. as I saw in some manual on the internet, but it didn't worked for me.

I'm getting the following errors:

```
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

Again, I used a default installation of oracle 12c, except setting passwords and select server type, I didn't changed much.

What I'm looking is a simple "todo list" to configure connection in the sql developer, to connect, even from a remote machine, to oracle 12c DB.

BTW: (if its matter)

1. I have 2 versions of sql developer: 4.1.2.20, and the original from instalation: 3.2.20.10.
2. I'm currently working on windows server 2008 OS.

Thanks,

**EDIT:**

Query:

```
SQL> select name, open_mode from v$pdbs where name='PDBORCL';
```

Result:

```
NAME      OPEN_MODE
--------  ----------
PDBORCL   READ WRITE
```

Command line:

```
lsnrctl service
```

Result:

```
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 30-MAY-2016 13:26:20

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.19.58)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
        LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
```

I've tried to use service name CLRExtProc.
Now I have the following error:

```
Status: Failure -Test failed: The Network Adapter could not established the connection
```

listener.ora file:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\Administrator\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Administrator\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\Administrator\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.19.58)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

tnsnames.ora

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\Administrator\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.19.58)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
#this is my addition I guess it not written properly
PDBORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.19.58)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdborcl)
    )
  )
```

**EDIT:**

command:
    lsnrctl STATUS LISTENER

```
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 30-MAY-2016 14:22
:08

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.19.58)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                29-MAY-2016 17:33:36
Uptime                    0 days 20 hr. 48 min. 36 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\Administrator\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\app\Administrator\diag\tnslsnr\DevOraRX\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.19.58)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

**EDIT: Full Solution**

This is how it works:

1. Install a fresh copy of oracle 12c (i did a desktop installation).
2. Changes in the `listener.ora`:

   - in the SID_LIST_LISTENER I added the following section: `(SID_DESC =(SID_NAME = pdborcl)(ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1))`
   - in the LISTENER instead of `HOST=127.0.0.1`, I set it to  `HOST=0.0.0.0`
3. restart oracle listener service.

now in the sql developer:

login as sys user:

```
Username: sys
Password: ****
Connection type: Basic, Role: SYSDBA
Hostname: localhost
Port: 1521
SID: orcl
```

Now check if pdb is up:

```
SQL> select name, open_mode from v$pdbs where name='PDBORCL';
```

If it is in mounted mode then,

```
SQL> alter pluggable database pdborcl open;
```

Create the user + grant permissions:

```
alter session set container=pdborcl;
create user demo identified by password QUOTA unlimited on users account unlock;
grant create session to demo;
grant create table to demo;
```

Connect as demo user in sql developer:

```
Username: demo
Password: ****
Connection type: Basic, Role: default
Hostname: localhost
Port: 1521
Service name: pdborcl
```

And, again, Thanks to JSapkota.

Now I'm trying to figure the sqlplus and instant client connection strings to pdbs...

Comment: I added detailed, step by step, solution. Look in the **EDIT: Full Solution** at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all check whether your pluggable database is opened or not.

```
SQL> select name, open_mode from v$pdbs where name='PDBORCL';
```

If it is in mounted mode then,

```
SQL> alter pluggable database pdborcl open;
```

Now on SQL Developer Create new connection as,

**Connection Name:** demo-pdborcl

**Username:** demo

**Password:** *****

**Connection Type:** Basic(If you wish to use TNS connection type you have to create TNS Network Alias in client side.)

**Hostname:** ip/dns

**Port:** 1521

**SID:** (If you use SID like 'ORCL' you will be connected to root container, therefore use Service name instead of SID)

**Service name:** (You can get your pdb's service name by firing `$ lsnrctl serivce`, also you can use `USE_SID_AS_SERVICE_listener` parameter on `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/listner.ora` file as `USE_SID_AS_SERVICE_listener=on` and any given SID will be treated as service name.

Some useful links-

[Creating a Database Connection Using SQL Developer](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-0DE0C9F4-8800-4142-A755-14B2FAA6624F.htm#ADMQS12420)

[Connect HR/SYS user with SQL Developer in Oracle12c Using TNS Service](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLFjwyHCEqk)

[Connecting to a Container Database (CDB)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-connecting-to-cdb-and-pdb-12cr1)

[USE_SID_AS_SERVICE_listener_name](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/listener.htm#NETRF2090)

Comment: Thanks again, can you please see the Edit in the end of my question and tell me if you see a problem?

Comment: Have you set the `local_listener` parameter? I got that updated error because that's not the service which connects to you the pdb.

Comment: I guess not. How can I do it?

Comment: I get ORA-02097: parameter cannot be modified because because specified value is invalid.  .... ORA-00132: syntax error or unresolved network name 'LISTENER' .

Comment: Add this to listener.ora file under SID_LIST_LISTENER  `(SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = pdborcl)
      (ORACLE_HOME = path to oracle home)
    )` you try adding quotation mark around listener name to avoid ora-02097.

Comment: Still the same (ORA-02097:), should I restart the oracle service?

Comment: Reinstalled the server and change ip in the listener to any, and reopen pdborcl and now it works.