# cannot connect my oracle server to developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, connectivity

I get the following error: Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS: listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor.  My services are below and my connection window.  I believe the installation of oracle 12c was a success.  Do you guys know what could be wrong, please.
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiBIn.png)

[image]

Comment: I think you are making mistake to give user connection name "SYS as SYSDBA'. First unlock the user like (alter user 'hr' identified by hr account unlock;)

Comment: Is the database instance started? (OracleServiceorcl10 service). What is the output of `lsnrctl status`?

Comment: orcl10 has an instance, but not OracleServiceorcl10.  I get the following message:

Comment: Service "orcl10" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl10", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...

Comment: Service "orcl10XDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl10", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orcl9" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl9", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orcl9XDB" has 1 instance(s).
  I also get: Instance "orcl9", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "pdborcl" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl10", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  Instance "orcl9", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

Comment: i also get:LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 24-JAN-2018 10:03:58

Comment: Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1523)))
STATUS of the LISTENER

Comment: ------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                24-JAN-2018 05:14:29
Uptime                    0 days 4 hr. 49 min. 32 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF

Comment: Listener Parameter File   C:\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\log\diag\tnslsnr\DESKTOP-7TRQ023\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...

Comment: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1523)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1523ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=DESKTOP-7TRQ023)(PORT=5501))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=D:\admin\orcl10\xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))

Comment: Why do you have (at least) 3 different listener processes, as shown in your screen shot of Windows services?  You should be running only one single listener, from the highest version Oracle home installed.  My guess is you are hitting the wrong listener, and that is born out by the fact your SQL Dev connection specifies port 1521, but the listener output you show indicates port 1523.  Just use one listener, on port 1521, and make sure LOCAL_LISTENER is null in all of your databases.

Comment: when I stopped orcl9 listener and connected using the port 1523, it worked.  Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: please edit the question and add this information but do not post it as comment.

Answer (score -1):

**First Logged in SQLPlus and Unlock the user**

Run **SQLPlus**, connect as **SYS** user (use administrator's password you have entered during installation) . Suppose that here For your test connection unlock **HR** user and give him a new password:

```
C:\>sqlplus  sys as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Wed Jan 24 12:15:51 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> alter user hr identified by new_password;

User altered.

SQL> alter user hr account unlock;

User altered.
```

**For Creating a Database Connection**

The first step to managing database objects using Oracle SQL Developer is to create a database connection.Perform the following steps:

1. Open Oracle SQL Developer.
2. In the Connections navigator, right-click Connections and select New Connection.
3. Enter test for the Connection Name (or any other name that identifies your connection), hr for the Username and Password, specify your `localhost` for the `Hostname` and enter `ORCL10`(in your case, as it showing in your attached picture) for the `SID`. Click Test.
4. The status of the connection was tested successfully. The connection was not saved however. Click Save to save the connection, and then click Connect.

For further your ref [Here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/sqldev/sqldev_mngdb/sqldev_mngdb_otn.htm) , [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33218201/connecting-sql-developer-to-oracle-12c) & [Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139875/how-to-configure-sql-developer-with-oracle-12c)

Comment: This is irrelevant to this error.

Comment: @ Balazs Papp , As per OP screen shot , it seems like that OP didn't unlock the connection user . Even though OP is not giving the proper connection name in SQL Developer. May be this is primary troubleshooting for making a connection.

Comment: This has nothing to do with users. The connection request does not even reach the database so it does not get to the authentication phase. This is very clear from the error.

Answer (score -1):

I tried altering the user In SQL plus but I get the following error.  But, thanks for the response.

Also, I cannot remember my user name.  But, I know the administrative password.
[image]

Comment: I can login using '\ as sysdba'  It says connect to 12c standard edition release ...

Comment: Why did you repeat the sqlplus command when you were clearly being prompted for a username?  The simple command (at the OS command line) 'sqlplus / as sysdba' will connect you as SYS to the database specified by the current setting of ORACLE_SID. Since you obviously have multiple databases of multiple versions, you should create a command file for each, to set ORACLE_SID and ORACLE_HOME appropriately.

Comment: when i stopped the service orcl9 and just had orcl10 open, and used the port 1523, then it worked. Thanks all.

Comment: this is not an answer. please edit the question and add this information and then delete this answer.

Answer (score -1):

1. Ensure that you are on the correct home
2. Ensure that the listener is started
3. Make sure that the listener, tnsnames files include the database entries